# Is there a way to implement custom buttons or widget in android studio replacing the default buttons and widgets of android studio?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing a simple android app with 6 buttons (Android default look), my need is to implement the custom buttons (what I mean by custom, is I am adding a link of 'pintrest' which shows the button type by look and feel).

My expected result is buttons which can show corners, some effects, shades as shown in link below.

https://www.pinterest.com/pin/378372806183575443/

Answer (score 2):

You can override styles in the res/values/styles.xml file

Or

You can create your own button, it can look like this:

```
    class BorderedButton : Button {

        constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
            init(context, null, null)
        }

        constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
            init(context, attrs, null)
        }

        constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
            init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr)
        }

        override fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyleAttr: Int?) {
            this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.round_bordered_button_accent)
            this.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorAccent))
            this.defaultFont()
        }
    }
```

then use it in your xml like this:

```
<com.xxx.xxx.shared.custom_ui.buttons.BorderedButton
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/done" />
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can change that in android studio and add it as resources for the specific button. It can be a gif or image or anything u like.